# Authentication credentials were not provided (React and Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, djoser

I'm finding difficulty fixing the named error while trying to login user using djoser jwt authentication. I'm using axios in react with Django backend. The access and referesh tokens appear in the browser local storage each time I login. When I referesh the browser the tokens are cleared. Since new tokens are being generated, why am I getting the named error?

```
Auth Action
_____________
import axios from 'axios';
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL, USER_LOADED_SUCCESS, USER_LOADED_FAIL,} from './types';


export const load_user = () => async dispatch =>{
    if(localStorage.getItem('access')){
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        try{
        const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/me/`, config)

        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        })
        
    }
        catch (err){
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED_FAIL,
            })
        }
    }else {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED_FAIL,
        })
    }
```

Comment: 403 means the request DID go through, the server just refuses to process it. I'd suggest to inspect the request in your browser's devtools to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Check to make sure that your token isn't expired. If that isn't the case then @timotgl point is definetely the way to go

Comment: Thanks  so much. The token isn't expired. Also the error I see in browser console and server (Django) console are the same and completely helpless. From browser dev tools the RESPONSE HEADER is reading ANONYMOUS. It seems the issue is from the request header but I'm not sure about that, I don't any other header to use other than that one in the code above.

Comment: @C-Bizz If the jwt is not expired, maybe the claims it contains are somehow not accepted by the server? You can check with https://jwt.io/ what's inside and maybe add some more logging on the server side to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot@timotgl for the link. I have been able to find out the cause. Response I'm getting from response tab in chrome is `Authentication credentials were not provided`. But I the access an referesh tokens appear appear in browser lol local storage each time I login